# Restsharp GET Call Works, but POST is Unauthorized?

Tags: c#, rest, post, get, restsharp

I'm working on a RestSharp API caller for challonge.com, and I've run into a problem with authorization.  When making a GET call, everything works properly and I can acquire the information I need.  However, when attempting a POST call, the status code returns as Unauthorized, despite using the same API key.  I've tried including the key in the request body and as a parameter, but neither seem to work.

Here are the calls that I am making:

-GET: https://api.challonge.com/v1/documents/tournaments/index

-POST: https://api.challonge.com/v1/documents/tournaments/create

And here is my code.

```
public class APICall
    {
        HttpUtility http = new HttpUtility();
        RestClient client = new RestClient("https://api.challonge.com/v1/");
        public string GetCall(string key)
        {
            client.AddDefaultHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            RestRequest request = new RestRequest("tournaments", DataFormat.Json);
            request.AddParameter("api_key", key);
            IRestResponse response = client.Get(request);
            return response.StatusCode.ToString();
        }
        public string PostCall(string tournName, string key)
        {
            client.AddDefaultHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            RestRequest request = new RestRequest("tournaments", DataFormat.Json);
            var obj = new Tournament(tournName,key);
            //request.AddParameter("api_key", key);
            request.AddJsonBody(obj);
            IRestResponse response = client.Post(request);
            return response.StatusCode.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should specify the characteristics of the client. In any case the line is commented. So the paramter wont be send. Also maybe the apikey is for header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Authentication**

All interactions with the API require a Challonge account with a verified email address and API key. We support HTTP basic authentication. Username = your Challonge username, Password = your API key. Many clients format these requests as: https://username:api-key@api.challonge.com/v1/... Or, if you prefer, you can just pass your API key as parameter api_key to all method calls.

So this should work at the start of your PostCall:

```
var userName = "your Challonge username";
var uNamePw = $"{userName}:{key}";

var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
var credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(encoding.GetBytes(uNamePw));

client.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", $"Basic {credentials}");
```

Alternatively you should be able to append `?api_key={your api key}` to the url

Comment: Adding an HTTP Basic authenticator worked.  Turns out this was an issue with RestSharp.  When using a GET call, using the API key as a parameter embeds it to the URL, but it doesn't do this when using a POST/PUT call.